# Why does audio not play in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, javascript-audio-api

I want to add background music to my website. I've tried this JS code:

```
var sound;
function initialAudio() {
    'use strict';
    sound = new Audio();
    sound.src = '../audio/test.mp3';
    sound.loop = true;
    sound.play();
}
window.addEventListener("load", initialAudio);
```

I have linked the JS and HTML, but when I open the site, the sound doesn't play. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you check the browser console? Since auto-playing audio is universally detested, browsers don't allow it.

Comment: how can i allow it?

Comment: that what appear in console Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: it should be allowed after the user have interacted with your page

Comment: It was a bad idea to have audio playing on your web site (without the users permission/action) and it is still a bad idea. If you want the user to play something then give them the option.

Comment: I will certainly give them option to mute audio, play or pause but how would I do that?

Comment: Which browser do you use? Did you check your src that it gets to the right file? As it works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aLpty6zx/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an audio element in your html, this is how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="audioContainer">
  <source src="myMp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playMp3()" type="button">Play Mp3</button>
<button onclick="pauseMp3()" type="button">Pause Mp3</button> 

<script>
const audioContainer = document.getElementById("audioContainer"); 

function playMp3() { 
  audioContainer.play(); 
} 

function pauseMp3() { 
  audioContainer.pause(); 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when someone inspect the page he will see the element and I think it isn't a professional way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

A modern browser will refuse to play *any* sound without user interaction. Your code should work fine, if started from a user event, like onclick.

Answer (score 1):

There's this javascript audio library called **HOWLER.JS** and its really easy to use. Include this script file:

```
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.1/howler.js"></script>
```

- Add this code snippet to your html:

  ```
  var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['../audio/test.mp3'],
      autoplay: true,
      loop: true,
      volume: 0.5,
  });

  sound.play();
  ```

For more info visit:
[HOWLER.JS DOCS](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the HTML5 audio element with the auto play attribute. As mentioned in the comments, browser support for `autoplay` is tenuous (for good reason) but it works for me in Firefox.

```html
<audio autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=464&type=wav"></source>
</audio>
```

If you want the user to be able to pause the audio, just add a `controls` attribute:

```html
<audio autoplay controls loop>
  <source src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=464&type=wav"></source>
</audio>
```

You can also use JS to have a button somewhere else on the page play/pause as used in another answer.

Comment: thanks but this is not my favorite way to do things. I mean come on we can make it invisible for someone who inspect the page.

Comment: @MuntadarMuhammad You can, but why? It doesn't make this site faster or provide any quantitative benefit, just more annoying and less open. On the other answer, you said it "isn't a professional way to do it." There are 2 things with that. It _is_ the professional way to do it. If you're really concerned with looking professional, background music _isn't_ professional. Besides, it will always show up in the JS under resources if someone looks close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done it in this way:

```
var sound = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');

sound.play();
```

This does not work in my case, so I did this:

```
 var sound = new Audio('sounds\\\tom-3.mp3');

 sound.play();
```